# Partitioning large MySQL table for search on varchar columns

Tags: mysql, innodb, partitioning

I have a MySQL InnoDB table with approximately 16.5 million records.  Searches are done by string search on id number, last name, first name, address, city, county.  All string values.  I am looking to speed up searches.  Indexes help but I am looking at partitions.  Would that help and what possible partition scheme would be most effective.  Using MySQL 5.7 and PHP for the lookup form.  Updates are rare.

Thanks in advance!

'voterlist', 'CREATE TABLE `voterlist` (\n  `COUNTY_CODE` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  `PRECINCT` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `VUID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,\n  `LAST_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `FIRST_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `MIDDLE_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `FORMER_LAST_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `SUFFIX` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `GENDER` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `DOB` datetime DEFAULT NULL,\n  `ADDRESS` varchar(110) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `PERM_HOUSE_NUMBER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `PERM_DESIGNATOR` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `PERM_DIRECTIONAL_PREFIX` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `PERM_STREET_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `PERM_STREET_TYPE` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `PERM_DIRECTIONAL_SUFFIX` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `PERM_UNIT_NUMBER` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `PERM_UNIT_TYPE` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `PERM_CITY` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `PERM_ZIP_CODE` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `MAILING_ADDRESS_1` varchar(110) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `MAILING_ADDRESS_2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `MAILING_CITY` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `MAILING_STATE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `MAILING_ZIPCODE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `EDR` datetime DEFAULT NULL,\n  `STATUS_CODE` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `SPANISH_SURNAME_FLAG` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `ELECTION_DATE` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `ELECTION_TYPE` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `ELECTION_PARTY` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `ELECTION_VOTING_METHOD` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `SOSFILENAME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `SIGNER` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `SIGNER_HH` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `TEL` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `EMAIL` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `FB` double DEFAULT NULL,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`VUID`),\n  KEY `idx_voterlist_LAST_NAME` (`LAST_NAME`),\n  KEY `idx_voterlist_FIRST_NAME` (`FIRST_NAME`),\n  KEY `idx_voterlist_PERM_CITY` (`PERM_CITY`),\n  KEY `SIGNER` (`SIGNER`),\n  KEY `idx_voterlist_ADDRESS` (`ADDRESS`,`PERM_UNIT_NUMBER`,`PERM_CITY`),\n  KEY `idx_voterlist_COUNTY` (`COUNTY_CODE`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

Select criter
ia will vary depending on the search combination.  They are

1. last_name like 'somevalue%';
2. first_name like 'somevalue%';
3. address like '%some street value  within address field%';
4. perm_city like '%some part of a city name string%';
5. county_code = someIntegerCountyCode;
6. vuid='somevalue';
7. dob = 'someDOB';

A select statement can contain any of these search criteria connected with and.
Most likely is last_name and perm_city but may include first_name.
16 million + rows

No real even division of rows between any of these as far as number

Comment: An easy one: Not at all.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (with or without partitioning, either way), plus the important `SELECTs`.  (I can't advise without more details.)  Partitioning is _not_ likely to help speed; Fulltext might.

Comment: Thanks.  edited the ask.  Appreciate your advice.